# event.source() returns null in android

Tags: java, android, xml, service, accessibilityservice

I'm implementing pasting clipboard text to another application's EditText view when activity change is detected by using accessibility service.

on my Accessibility Service, accessibility event detection works well. but when onAccessibilityEvent is called, the code event.getSource() returns null object.

```
public class ClipBoardPasteService extends AccessibilityService {

ClipboardManager clipboard;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("MyTag", "clipboard service created");
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    Log.i("MyTag", "ClipBoardPastedService : onAccessibilityEvent");
        clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

        AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
        Log.i("MyTag", "source name : " + source.getViewIdResourceName());
        source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);

}


@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Log.i("MyTag", "ClipBoardPastedService : onServiceConnected");
    String[] packages = {"com.google.android.talk"};

    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
    info.packageNames = packages;
    //AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED;
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    setServiceInfo(info);
  }
}
```

and this is part of  my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
        android:name=".ClipBoardPasteService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            <category android:name="android.accessibilityservice.category.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- from ICS -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
    </service>
```

this is accessibility_service_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/service_description"
    android:packageNames="@null"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.accessibility.ServiceSettingsActivity"
/>
```

I searched and found another stackoverflow's similar questions, but the answer "missing meta-data in Manifest" doesn't make sense. what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Not all event types have a source.  You should check that the event is of a type that has a source, and then handle those events differently.

For example TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED does not have a source, but TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED does.  You should read through the Android documentation thoroughly for this.  It is a bit confusing, though there is a logic to it.  If muddied up in poor documentation and API design.

Also note that in your configuration, your code is overriding your XML.  Get rid of your packagenames line in your xml.  And removed all of the code in your in your on service connected.  You are simply overriding the configuration you did in your service config XML file.

Finally, should there be some configuration you need to override using code, for some dynamic changes, you should always (read "almost always") do so like this:

```
AccessibilityServiceInfo info = getServiceInfo();
//modify info to your liking
setServiceInfo(info);
```

This ensures that you create a properly constructed service info, with the parameters from your XML for modification.  This is almost always what is intended over setting a completely new configuration.

Source:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and was able to able resolve it by adding this permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
    <service
       ...
    </service>
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by setting android:notificationTimeout to 100.

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged|typeWindowContentChanged"
android:packageNames="com.android.phone"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagReportViewIds|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
android:notificationTimeout="100"/>
```