# Passing Accessibility Event to backthread getting null

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, accessibilityservice, accessibility

Try to play with Android [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService), Passing [AccessibilityEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent) to AsyncTask but all values vanished in AccessibilityEvent like mEventTime becomes 0, mPackageName becomes null etc. Unable to understand whats going on here

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    new MyTestAsync().execute(event); //event not null 
}

 public class MyTestAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

        private AccessibilityEvent event;

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> doInBackground(Object... params) {
               this.event = (AccessibilityEvent) params[0]; //getting null values in event  like mEventTime = 0, mPackageName = null
}
}
```

capture following types of events

```
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged|typeViewFocused|typeWindowContentChanged"
```

Comment: You can pass accessibility extracted data to your async task but creating async task in onAccessibilityEvent() is very bad bcz this method will get called on every event and there is restriction on number of async task in system

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig you remind me good point about a number of AsyncTask restriction, but my main motive is do all processing in the background after getting AccessibilityEvent. Yes I can pass accessibility extracted data to my async task but try to understand why getting null.

Comment: hey man did you got anything ??

Comment: Not till now...

Comment: You got any solution for this? Even I am facing the similar issue.

Comment: @suv : No remember exactly but I think I used Handler & pass the event object to that handler in thread.

Comment: I did it without handler but i found no use of doing it because it will generate events one by one but i wanted that events in stack formation just like a list of all nodes for that page.

Answer (score 2):

The Event object is reusable by the OS. The receiver doesn't own it. The operating system doesn't create new events constantly. In fact, under normal circumstances it creates only very few reusable (maybe even only 1). By doing the work on the Event in a Background thread, the values within the event object are completely invalidated by the time you get around to doing work on them. You're lucky that they're all null, and not something random that would have lead you to believe this approach is pseudo working.

Solution: Create your own event wrapper, copying the values from event that you need, and pass that to your AsyncTask instead.

Comment: i appreciate your reply, please provide a sample if possible.

Comment: Chris How to create an event wrapper?

Comment: The solution is not useful if you have to crawl the AccessibilityNode tree associated to the event.

Use AccessibilityEvent.obtain(originalEvent) to create a copy, then pass that to the background thread.

Answer (score 1):

The event object you get handed over to you in `AccessibilityService#onAccessibilityEvent` is only valid during that method call.

If you need to defer working with it, you can use `AccessibilityEvent.obtain(originalEvent)` to make a copy, and pass that new object around.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78226322/4882029

it took me 2 week to discover this solution